# Save user input from a switch-case that is stored in a list (beginner) C#

Tags: c#, list, methods, switch-statement

For each switch loop that is performed, all information that the user has entered is deleted.
The user provides information via case 1 which has the methods: läsPoäng (readPoints) and omvandlaBetyg (convertRate).

How can I proceed to make the loop remember the user's input?

I have different lists that consist of different variables used for my methods.
Comments have been added to give a better explanation.

I appreciate all help I can get.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> ämnen = new List<string> { "Matematik", "Svenska", "Engelska", "Historia", "Fysik" };
        List<int> poäng = new List<int>(); // Declaration of list with points
        List<char> betyg = new List<char>(); // Declaration of list with grades

        bool repetera = true;


        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" \n========Räkna betyg========");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Skriv in dina poäng");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Skriv ut dina betyg");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Poäng & betyg statistik");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Avsluta");
            Console.WriteLine("==========================");
            Console.Write("Ange ditt alternativ: ");
            int alternativ = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (alternativ)
            {
                // I want to be able to save the input from the user in case 1
                // so that it can be used in other cases.
                case 1:
                    läsPoäng(ämnen);        // Method that asks for the user to input points for specific courses
                    omvandlaBetyg(poäng);   // Method that converts user input to char "grades"
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    skrivUtBetyg(betyg, ämnen); // Method that show grades for each course
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Statistik(betyg, poäng); // Method that show statistics for the points and grades
                    break;

                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Tack för att du använt programmet 'Räkna betyg'");
                    repetera = false;
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nVänligen ange ett alternativ mellan 1-4.\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (true);

    }
    // Method that asks for the user to input points for specific courses
    static List<int> läsPoäng(List<string> ämnen)
    {
        var poäng = new List<int>();

        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för matematik:");
        poäng.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för svenska:");
        poäng.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för engelska:");
        poäng.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för historia:");
        poäng.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

        Console.Write("Ange totalpoäng för fysik:");
        poäng.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

        return poäng;
    }
    // Method that converts user input to char "grades"
    static List<char> omvandlaBetyg(List<int> poäng)
    {
        List<char> betyg = new List<char>();

        foreach (int i in poäng)
        {
            if (i < 50)
            {
                betyg.Add('F');
            }
            else if (i <= 60)
            {
                betyg.Add('E');
            }
            else if (i < 75)
            {
                betyg.Add('D');
            }
            else if (i < 90)
            {
                betyg.Add('C');
            }
            else if (i < 100)
            {
                betyg.Add('B');
            }
            else
            {
                betyg.Add('A');
            }
        }
        return betyg; 
    }
    // Method that show grades for each course
    static void skrivUtBetyg(List<char> betyg, List<string> ämnen)
    {
        // Använder mig utav metoden .Zip för att slå ihop betyget med
        // sitt motsvarande ämne. För att sedan kunna presentera allt 
        // i samma linje som visar betyget och ämnet "zippat" till en linje.
        // (Utan denna .Zip lösning så hade man fått göra två separate foreach-loopar
        // som då visar ämnena och betygen separat. 
        // Denna lösning fungerar utmärkt för att iterera igenom två listor samtidigt.

        var betygOchÄmnen = betyg.Zip(ämnen, (first, second) => first + "         |" + second);

        Console.WriteLine(" \n_________________________");
        Console.WriteLine("|  Betyg    |   Ämne     ");

        foreach (var item in betygOchÄmnen)
        {   
             Console.WriteLine("| " + item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("_________________________");
    }
    // Method for showing grade and points statistics
    static void Statistik(List<char> betyg, List<int> poäng) 
    {
        int betygA = 0;
        int betygC = 0;
        int betygF = 0;
        int totalPoäng = poäng.Sum();
        
        foreach (var c in betyg)
        {
            if (c == 'A')
            {
                betygA++;
            }
            else if (c == 'C')
            {
                betygC++;
            }
            else if (c == 'F')
            {
                betygF++;
            }
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(" \n========================");
        Console.WriteLine("|Antal A betyg: " + betygA + "      |");
        Console.WriteLine("|Antal C betyg: " + betygC + "      |");
        Console.WriteLine("|Antal F betyg: " + betygF + "      |");
        Console.WriteLine("|Antal betygspoäng: " + totalPoäng + "|");
        Console.WriteLine("========================");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please read the SO guidelines, on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been found.
I had to add a list for the input to be stored into.

As you can see below:

```
poäng = läsPoäng(ämnen);
betyg = omvandlaBetyg(poäng);
```